# The touchpad is freezed(Ubuntu 22.04). it is not moving not even the right-click

Tags: 22.04

My laptop is on dual booting mode(Ubuntu and Winodws) . When I login to Windows my touchpad works fine but not in Ubuntu. If I login in Ubuntu it freezes . this problem have been arising from 4months but after sometimes it started working. But this time it is totally freezed. The touchpad have not been working since last month